# UTF8 Character Makes File Inaccessible

Tags: linux, filesystems, unicode, character-encoding

If I run:

```
scp me@example.com:/home/me/cömmön_file.jpg /home/me/
```

from my remote server I get:

> scp: /home/me/cömmön_file.jpg: No such file or directory

If I swap out the utf8 characters though with a wildcard it will work:

```
scp me@example.com:/home/me/c?mm?n_file.jpg /home/me/
```

and/or

```
scp me@example.com:/home/me/c*mm*n_file.jpg /home/me/
```

If I use the AWS CLI on my remote machine the behavior also replicates.

Running other commands with the explicit name in them on my remote machine functions as I'd expect.

e.g.

```
ls -lha /home/me/cömmön_file.jpg
```

> -rw-r--r--. 1 me me 1.1M Jan 15 21:58 /home/me/cömmön_file.jpg

I can rename the file as well with `mv`.

Is the problem with transmitting the file, or something underlying in my machine hosting the file?

The UTF8 character causing the current issue is https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0308 but I suspect other characters also would reproduce the issue. If I try to rename the file from `ö` to https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F6 my machine tells me the files are the same.

> mv: ‘/home/me/cömmön_file.jpg’ and ‘/home/me/cömmön_file.jpg’ are the same file

The server hosting the file is:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
```

and its `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

the server requesting the file is:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
```

and its `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What's the locale running on both instances ? (Type `locale`)
This type of problems might happen when  both side don't use the same locale (preferably a `.UTF-8` ending one).

Comment: @DrYak I've updated the question with that info, both look the same to me.

Comment: Damn, same locale...

 - does using `rsync` instead of  `scp` also barf on that file ?

Comment: Nope, your Mac betrayed you that you're a Mac user, and that's where the whole thing stems from.
'ö' and 'ö' just aren't the same Unicode codepoint and that's something that Linux conserves (just like it's also case sensitive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution:
do not use accented letters on your keyboard, use tab-complete instead (and have your SSH key setup so that tab-complete also works with over the network `scp`, `rsync`, etc.) or fall back to wild cards, because what you experience is the normal intended behaviour.

---

It doesn't work, because **you did not type the same filename**.

Seems crazy ? That's UTF-8 to you.

Even more crazy: I can use my *magical remote mind-reading psychic power* to tell you that you have an **Apple Mac**.

More seriously: that's the crucial information you forgot to give when asking your question, but that you accidentally leaked when typing the question itself.

---

While copy-pasting the answer above:

```
# echo "scp me@example.com:/home/me/cömmön_file.jpg" | hexdump -C
00000000  73 63 70 20 6d 65 40 65  78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 63  |scp me@example.c|
00000010  6f 6d 3a 2f 68 6f 6d 65  2f 6d 65 2f 63 6f cc 88  |om:/home/me/co..|
00000020  6d 6d 6f cc 88 6e 5f 66  69 6c 65 2e 6a 70 67 20  |mmo..n_file.jpg |
00000030  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 6d 65  2f 0a                    |/home/me/.|
0000003a
```

Please pay close attention to how the letter 'ö' is coded : `6f cc 88`. A litteral 'o' followed by an extra UTF-8 codepoint. (in fact, on my terminal it doesn't even display as 'ö' but as 'o')

When when I (=Linux user) type:

```
echo /home/me/cömmön_file.jpg | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 6d 65  2f 63 c3 b6 6d 6d c3 b6  |/home/me/c..mm..|
00000010  6e 5f 66 69 6c 65 2e 6a  70 67 0a                 |n_file.jpg.|
0000001b
```

Again look closely at the 'ö' symbol : `c3 b6`, an entirely different UTF-8 code point and no extra litteral ASCII.

---

Ultra short explanation : [UTF-8 normalization (composition vs decomposition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

---

Longer explanation :

in Unicode, there are multiple way to code for something that looks like 'ö'.

- first way is *composed characters* : there's a code point that's litteraly 'ö' inherited from Latin-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1:1998) code points, Unicode codepoint U+00f6 (coded as c3 b6 in UTF-8)
- second way is *decomposed characters* : you first output the ASCII o, and then append a special code point [that means '*Please combine an umlaut to the preceding letter*'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), Unicode codepoint U+0308 (coded as cc 88 in UTF-8)

it's this combining character that enable you to do all the̫ ͨcra̎zy shit̫ ĺiͭke̬̓ ̭Z͉̒a̅l̞gͩoͤ ̤͋aṅd̲ ̹ͨallͦ ̍ͅthͅe oͅt͔̅h̦̊e̠r ͔̋dḁŕ͕k̓ ̃m͍o͉ͅñ͎͖̉s̺͑tr̰͎̈́ỏ͖ͧsi̮͂͑t̚i͙̗ės͓̊̒ ̞ͯt̗͕ẖ̈ͩá̝ṱ̟͒ ͓͐ͦl̈́ṵ̿r͈̾k̼̝ͭ̍ ̹i͖̇̈́n͚̳ ͖̗ͦt͓h̿e͖ ̌m̳͌̽a̪ͥd̺͑n͕͌̐e̿͊s͇s̘͓͊ ̗̈́ö̫́f͕̞ ͕̰̓ìṅ̠sͤ̂a̬̝̿ͪn̘ͫ͆e̜ͯ ̩͓ͣẻ͛ḽ̞̃ḓ̺r̙̦ͥͬi̫̠̔ͮt̰̓̾ͅč͕ͦḧ̞̱͖́̒̽ ͇̳ḁ̖̊̈b̏͑o̳̙̍m̩̪̞ͦi̇ͮn̳͔ͨ̏ͤa̤̯ͣṱ̰ͥï̺̄o̞͖̿n͆ͦs̬̍ ̹ͩ͒th̞̄a̗̗͐͌ͪt͂ ̬̞iͭ̒s̘͇ ̱̯̐̆̒Ũ̺̞̘ͯT̩̀̔̚F̪͒̄-̪̘̈́8̮̆̍͂.̱͍̂

hum.

The rest of the planet uses composed characters whenever possible (because it's more compact and also because it uses the range of Unicode that is compatible with Latin-1, simplifying backward compatibility) and only resort to combining characters for thing that don't have their own code point (mostly less frequent languages).

Apple lives apparently on a different planet, and they have decided that they try to always use combining characters (because they worship the dark lord Za͓̙̘͌l̦̖͉̃ͦ͆͊ͧ̀g͖̭̼̗͉̦̬̍̀̌ͬ̓ͥ҉o̧͉̗̱̥̣̯͍̗̲̩ͪ͋̾͑̈́ͦ̐̓͘͡ ?).

Typing the keyboard letter that looks like 'ö' simply doesn't generate the same binary sequence depending on which computer you type the key.

Then comes into play another thing : most Unix tend to use file systems (like Linux' EXT4) which are sensitive to case AND sensitive to Unicode coding (where UTF-8 is supported). They try to preserve whether the text was composed or not. Thus they make a distinction between the UTF-8 binary sequence `6f cc 88` and `c3 b6` even if they code for the same end result 'ö'.  (the same way the make a distinction between 'A' and 'a' even if its the same latin letter).
So your 'ö' produced by your keyboard and the 'ö' on the server are not the same.

It happens that stack exchange just store whatever Unicode coding you throw at it as-is, leading to mythical answers as the [HTML RegEx parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/16168) ones. (Thus your Mac betrayed itself by the specific byte sequence that recorded 'ö').

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. The tab worked, and when I use debug mode on the AWS CLI I see it sending as `%C3%B6` so Terminal was giving the wrong character.

Comment: It was my pet peeve that I had sysops that insisted in using localized unicode/UTF-8 chars in filenames, DNS and DHCP configurations...Best avoiding them altogether.